# Rollbacks in transactional DDL statements for innodb in MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, innodb, transaction

System:
**MySQL 8.0,
Storage engine - Innodb**

In a given scenario, I obtain an explicit transaction in application layer, and run some DDL and DML statements.
If tx fails, I roll-back it. But only DML statements roll-back.

1. Do I need to explicitly enable support for transactional DDL statements for InnoDB? It does not seem to be the case as per MySQL's documentation as it does not mention anything such.
2. Is roll-back for DDL statement supported only when DDL statement itself fails, and the DB level transaction in which it ran is rolled back, and not the explicit transaction I used in application layer?

Comment: Read user manual about statements which causes immediate commit.